# writing to and reading from storage in beam python (on dataflow)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to write a pipeline where an earlier stage calls a cpp binary which writes tfrecords to gcs, via [gcs cpp api](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp#quickstart),
and a later stage reads the tfrecords (to shuffle them etc).

How should I do this?

The following does not work as `model_dir` is empty when the pipeline is built.

```
def foo():
  p = subprocess.run(["cpp_binary", "--output_dir", "./model_dir"])

_ = (p
     | MapTuple(foo, ...)  # writing
     | beam.io.ReadFromTFRecord("./model_dir/*")  # reading, to reshuffle etc.
```

Splitting writing and reading into two pipelines work, but the overhead to start 2 pipelines (starting workers, scaling up the number of workers etc) is high.